# Problem sending model properties from Html Form to [HttpPost] Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

I have a html form like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_YariMamulEkle", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@id ="YariMamulKaydetForm" }))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.Label("Yarı Mamul Stok Kodu", new {@class= "form-label"})
                </div>
                <div class=" row">

                    <select class=" form-select" id="chosenYariMamulStock">
                        <option selected disabled hidden>Seçiniz</option>
                        @foreach (var item in (List<YariMamulStock>)@ViewBag.seededYariMamuls)
                        {
                                <option value ="@item" data-foo="@item.YariMamulStockName"> @item.YariMamulStockCode</option>
                                
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.Label("Stok Adı", new {@class = "form=label"})
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x =>x.YariMamulStockName, new {@id = "disableStockName", @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"})
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.Label("Yarı Mamul (Kg)", new {@class = "form-label"})
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YariMamulStockKg, new {@id = "yariMamulStockKg", @class= "form-control" })
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="YeniMamulKaydet" type="submit">Tamam</button>
                    <button class="btn" type="button">Iptal</button>
                </div>
                
            }
```

I change the value inside YariMamulStockName TextBox with this code, which is originally disabled

```
 $(function () {
            $('#chosenYariMamulStock').change(function () {
                var selected = $(this).find('option:selected')
                var sendDataDisable = selected.data('foo')
                $('#disableStockName').val(sendDataDisable);
            });
        });
```

I am trying to send values to this Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _YariMamulEkle(YariMamulStock yariMamul)
        {

            TempYariMamulList.Add(yariMamul);
            ViewBag.YariMamulList = TempYariMamulList;

            foreach (var item in db.YariMamulStocks)
            {
                if (item.isSeeded == true)
                {
                    seededYariMamuls.Add(item);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.SeededYariMamuls = seededYariMamuls;

            return RedirectToAction("FormEkle");
```

I am trying to send these 3 properties [**YariMamulStockCode**, **YariMamulStockName** , **YariMamulStockKg**]

```
public class YariMamulStock
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string YariMamulStockCode { get; set; }

        public string YariMamulStockName { get; set; }

        public int YariMamulStockKg { get; set; }

        public bool? isSeeded { get; set; }
    }
```

I can send [**YariMamulStockKg**] value and can see in the ActionResult Post modal parameter but the other 2 property is not showing.

**YariMamulStockCode** property is which we can choose from selectlist is sending null Value.

**YariMamulStockName** property is which filled in jquery lines is sending null Value.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for helping !

GET ACTION FOR METHOD

```
public ActionResult _YariMamulEkle()
        {

            ViewBag.YariMamulList = TempYariMamulList;

            foreach (var item in db.YariMamulStocks)
            {
                if (item.isSeeded == true)
                {
                    seededYariMamuls.Add(item);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.SeededYariMamuls = seededYariMamuls;


            return PartialView();
        }
```

Data inside the Viewbag.seededYariMamuls  is

```
List<YariMamulStock> seededYariMamuls = new List<YariMamulStock>();

new YariMamulStock{YariMamulStockCode = "132L.146S-1", YariMamulStockName = "Şeker",isSeeded =true},
                new YariMamulStock{YariMamulStockCode = "132L-2", YariMamulStockName = "Su", isSeeded=true},
                new YariMamulStock{YariMamulStockCode = "132L-3", YariMamulStockName = "Limon",isSeeded =true},
                new YariMamulStock{YariMamulStockCode = "146S-2", YariMamulStockName = "Kauçuk",isSeeded =true},
                new YariMamulStock{YariMamulStockCode = "146S-2", YariMamulStockName = "Mısır Özü",isSeeded =true},
```

Comment: Can you show Get action for this view. pls?

Comment: at the end of the page i put the get action. That action is a Partial View of some other action @Serge

Comment: Thanks, And I  need YariMamulStock class too. And I can't see where you defined seededYariMamuls

Comment: i already put that class between the Post action and images @serge

Comment: Because the data is not rendered to html correctly, if you use normal submit rather than ajax post, the browser will send the 'value' field of your select control, however, you bind an c# object instance(rather than a string or other primitive type), better to check what the extract data the browser send to server is.

Comment: @Serge i define seededYariMamuls list in the same class that the controllers in.

Comment: @dexiang okay now i understand what do you mean, i already try using ajax post but because of that Form is inside PartialView and i need to send parameters to PartialView, ajax post send datas to ParentView because PartialView did not have url. That is why i need to change

Comment: I am sorry but it is hard to see what is going on.  You have a half of code somewhere behind and a half of data is in ViewBags.  I don' t think that it is a good idea. The most of your code should be redone. It is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @Serge the only ViewBag that you will need to use is ViewBag.SeededYariMamuls which i editted in the code. Only 5 datas are inside that viewbag and i unpacked them as a List<YariMamulStock>

Comment: @Serge by the way thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Okay i solved the problem by adding inside  tag a name attribute the property that i want my model back

```
<select name = "YariMamulStockCode">
```

Then i add in  tags value attribute same property in my model

```
<option value = "YariMamulStockCode">
```

That solved **[YariMamulStockCode]** problem.

Than i change

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YariMamulStockName, new { @id = "disableStockName", @class = "form-control", @disabled= "disabled" })
```

With

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YariMamulStockName, new { @id = "disableStockName", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

That solved **[YariMamulStockName ]** problem